# How to check if WordPress plugin is installed and activated?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I want to check if Yoast SEO is installed in WordPress. I have activated Yoast SEO in my Test Environment, but it's not working out.

In the **wp-seo-main.php** of Yoast, there's this line on line 16:

```
define( 'WPSEO_VERSION', '3.4' );
```

So I thought, that's a good line to check if Yoast is installed and running, so I did:

```
if ( defined( 'WPSEO_VERSION' ) ) {
    echo '<script>alert("Yes, defined");</script>';
} else {
    echo '<script>alert("No, undefined");</script>';
}
```

But it gives me "No, undefined". How weird, because it should be defined.

Anyone got an idea? I'm totally out of ideas.

Comment: keep in mind wordpress.stackexchange.com as well, your question may be more suitable there

Comment: @YakovL Yes but I thought this was more of a PHP related thing, but turns out there are wordpress functions for it.

Comment: Please check out my function. It contains a lot to do a good and stable check by using wp functions!

Comment: is **The relevant question here** is  if Yoast is installed **and running** or just "installed"? The latter I wonder _When do we need to know if an in-active plugin is in the plugin folder?_ So I suppose as written in the question "...and running" is the answers we should give.

Answer (score 15):

Or without extra inclusions, front end or back end:

```
if ( in_array( 'wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
    // do stuff only if Yoast is installed and active
}
```

Works with any plugin, just look into your *plugins folder* for your target: `plugin-folder/plugin-index-name.php` where the latter shuld resident the Plugin details at the top inside the file.

Please Check Doc. [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_plugin_active/)

Comment: Thats not correct!!!!! This checks if a plugin is active. If it's inactive but installed, it won't appear in here.

Comment: @Mr.Jo the question is more then the "stackoverflow title". As the topic context searching solution is "a good line to check if Yoast is installed and running..." Therefor the answer is correct.

Comment: Yes it's correct for checking if it's active but not for checking if it's installed. I'll post a correct answer below to check both the correct way...

Answer (score 4):

```
$all_plugins = get_plugins();

//print_r( $all_plugins );

if( array_key_exists( 'woolementor/woolementor.php', $all_plugins ) ){

     //do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by Jonas Lundman's answer I wrote this to handle also when Yoast premium is active.

```
function is_yoast_active() {
    $active_plugins = apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) );

    foreach ( $active_plugins as $plugin ) {
        if ( strpos( $plugin, 'wp-seo' ) ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below code:

```
 <?php include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php'; ?>
 <?php if ( is_plugin_active( 'wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php' ) ) :

      //do staff

 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This is just a copy of accepted answer, and this is added 2 years later.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all the others for doing a good job so far! But the question is also about a check if a plugin is installed and all your answers are only about checking if a plugin is active.

So I went to my playground and developed a correct check I want to show you by using functions WP already provided.

```
// Check if needed functions exists - if not, require them
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_plugins' ) || ! function_exists( 'is_plugin_active' ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';
}

/**
 * Checks if Yoast SEO is installed
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function is_wp_seo_installed(): bool {
    if ( check_plugin_installed( 'wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php' ) ) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Check if Yoast SEO is activated
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function is_wp_seo_active(): bool {
    if ( check_plugin_active( 'wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php' ) ) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Check if plugin is installed by getting all plugins from the plugins dir
 *
 * @param $plugin_slug
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function check_plugin_installed( $plugin_slug ): bool {
    $installed_plugins = get_plugins();

    return array_key_exists( $plugin_slug, $installed_plugins ) || in_array( $plugin_slug, $installed_plugins, true );
}

/**
 * Check if plugin is installed
 *
 * @param string $plugin_slug
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function check_plugin_active( $plugin_slug ): bool {
    if ( is_plugin_active( $plugin_slug ) ) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

As you can see I've wrote two separate functions to check if `Yoast SEO` is installed and active so I just need to call it and check the return param:

```
$installed = is_wp_seo_installed();
$active    = is_wp_seo_active();

if ( $installed && $active ) {
    echo 'WP SEO is installed and active!';
} else {
    echo 'WP SEO is not installed or active!';
}
```

But if you want to skip this two extra functions, you can call the two check functions directly:

```
$installed = check_plugin_installed( 'wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php' );
$active    = check_plugin_active( 'wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php' );

if ( $installed && $active ) {
    echo 'Yoast SEO is installed and active!';
} else {
    echo 'Yoast SEO is not installed or active!';
}
```

I hope this helps you to do a good installed & active check!

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

```php
if(count(
        preg_grep(
            '/^wordpress-seo.*\/wp-seo.php$/',
            apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins'))
        )
    ) != 0
){
    // Plugin activated
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this, to get all active plugin names;

```
$callback = function($key){
    $key = explode('/', $key);
    return $key[0];                                        
}

$active_plugins = array_map($callback, get_option( 'active_plugins' ) );
```